# Embedded System with PWM support

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded-systems

I need a Raspberry Pi sized (can be smaller or a bit larger) embedded computer that can output PWM signal natively.

The Raspberry Pi can output PWM signals, but only with a maximum resolution of 0.1mS. For my purposes

- I need one with a resolution of 0.05mS or lower. It must support 500Hz of refresh rate for the PWM signal.
- It must also run Linux or some other system that supports Java and wireless networking.
- The board must also have Java support for the PWM signal.
- The board could be two devices working together (e.g. something like a Arduino and a shield).
- The board must cost less than $70.